# $\Pi ({1+z^{2^n}})$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that
pact sets $\Pi  ({1+z^{2^n}})$

converges uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disk. Show that limit is $1/(1+z)$

I cant even start!

Comment: Did you mean to say "Prove that $\prod (1 + z^{2^n})$ converge uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disk."?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|z^{2^n}| \leq |z|^n$ gives you uniform convergence. To show the limit holds, calculate partial products and notice $\prod_0^k (1+z^{2^n}) = \sum_{0}^{2^k-1} z^k$. Thus the limit should be $\frac{1}{1-z}$.